# Ajax value of readyState is always other than 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I am running this codes where I am trying to show data based on user input , Now There's no error connection also happens properly but when I enter any name it always goes in the else part of readyState that is the value of readyState is never 4 .
  Could someone please let me know what is wrong in theses codes ?
Here's my JavaScript Code:

```
function ajax() {
  var xhr;
  console.log("test");
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    //xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  }
  var jsondata = "";
  xhr.open("POST", "index.php");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.success == 200) {
        jsondata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = jsondata[0].name;
      }
    } else {
      console.log("request is not completed");
      console.log(xhr.readyState);
    }
  }
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  var element = document.getElementById("sbmt");
  var elemenTxt = document.getElementById("txt");
  if (element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var store = elemenTxt.value;
      var storeVa = "datafound=" + store;
      console.log(store);
      console.log(storeVa);
      xhr.send(storeVa);
    })
  }
}

ajax();
```

And here's my PHP code :

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost,$username,$password);
mysqli_select_db($con,"trynew") or die(mysqli_error());
if (isset($_POST["datafound"])) {
$user = $_POST['datafound'];
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM trynewtable where name = '$user' ";
$all_result = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result==FALSE)
{
die(mysqli_error());
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$all_result[] = $row;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$jsondata = json_encode($all_result);
echo $jsondata; 
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What is the readyState value?

Answer (score 0):

After readyState it should be xhr.status and not success , I corrected it and it's working thanks everyone.